# Scheme unpack a list of list for a map

Tags: scheme

```
(map list (list 1 2 3) (list 4 5 6))
(define (interleave . args)
  (map list args))
(interleave (list 1 2 3) (list 4 5 6) (list 7 8 9))
```

The first function returns an interleave ((1 4) (2 5) (3 6))
Even better it will interleave on any number of lists (i need that)
However my interleave function returns (((1 2 3)) ((4 5 6)) ((7 8 9)))

How do I unpack the args lists so map can map the lists inside the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called `zip`:

```
(define (zip . args)
  (apply map list args))

(zip '(1 2 3) '(a b c) '(I II III))       ; ==> ((1 a I) (2 b II) (3 c III))
(apply zip '((1 a I) (2 b II) (3 c III))) ; ==> ((1 2 3) (a b c) (I II III))
```

You'll find `zip` in [SRFI-1 List Library](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html) and thus many implementations have a way to enable it or for r6rs you just include `(srfi :1)` in the import list.

You also have `unzip` which is `zip` but it takes a list of lists instead of many arguments. It's almost the opposite of `zip`:

```
(define (unzip lsts)
  (apply map list lsts))

(unzip '((1 a I) (2 b II) (3 c III))) ; ==> ((1 2 3) (a b c) (I II III))
(unzip '((1 2 3) (a b c) (I II III))) ; ==> ((1 a I) (2 b II) (3 c III))
```

In SRFI-1 you have `unzip1` ... `unzip5` that actually are closer to being opposite of `zip` since it returns multiple values:

```
(unzip3 '((1 a I) (2 b II) (3 c III))) ; ==> (1 2 3); (a b c); (I II III)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply`:

```
(define (interleave . args)
    (apply map list args))
```